# Rewrite a URL Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I’m attempting to rewrite a link on my Apache config file so that it looks like an internal link, but is actually external.

The link on my site will look like this, and have multiple querystrings.

```
http://www.mysite.com/myscript.asp?somevar=1&othervar=2
```

But when clicked will be rewritten as this:

```
http://www.othersite.com/script.asp?somevar=1&othervar=2
```

Here is where I am so far (not working):

```
RewriteRule ^myscript.asp?(.*)$ http://www.othersite.com/script.asp?(.*) [L]
```

Can anybody get this rule working? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this would be helpful:

```
RewriteRule ^myscript\.asp\?(.*)$ http://www.othersite.com/script.asp?$1 [L]
```

**Note**: question mark(?) and dot(.)  have special meaning in reqular expresion, so if you want to use them as **meaningless character** put `\` before them!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I forgot to escape the characters - thanks! However, I still cant get the updated code to work - any ideas?

Comment: @Matt what happens when go to script.asp

Comment: Hey, script.asp was the external website, so it just went there. I figured it out by using a redirect on a .htaccess as follows:`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.othersite.com/script.asp?$1 [L,R=302]` I placed this in its own folder `/myscript/` and used the following url on my site: `http://www.mysite.com/myscript/somevar=1&othervar=2`. This works quite well and does the job nicely - thanks for your help.